# When coding for html and writing multiple headers do I have to label each header and paragraph w a number?

Tags: html

When writing the code headers like h1, h2, and h3 do I have to write the paragraphs like p1,p2, and p3 or can I just put p? Also what text editor app is best for Macbook?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one type of `<p></p>` tag, no numeric modifiers ala headings.

Answer (score 0):

f you want to write code h1,h2,h3. every heading has diffrent size. exampale. h1 for title, h2 for sub title.
so you should write number after h and for p or paragraf you just write p. you do not need number after p. every p or paragraf is same size but if you give class css in p or pragraf.it will be different.
i hope, it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

because there are many heading tags, so you can choose them for your needs,
`<h1>` headings should be used for main headings, followed by `<h2>` headings, then the less important `<h3>`, and so on.

you can read [it here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp#:%7E:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,subject%20for%20the%20whole%20page.)

and it's about [paragraf tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp)